# Take output from C++ exe and work on it in Python in real time

Tags: python, c++, real-time, stdout, change-data-capture

I have a C++ executable, for an eye tracker, that printf's gaze coordinates to the terminal. I need to be able to get these into Python for data analysis etc. It would be awesome if there was a way that I could do this in real time, so I could manipulate the incoming data in python. The closest thing I've found to being useful is this: http://fluxtrap.blogspot.co.uk/2011/09/dead-simple-real-time-plotting-with-cc.html. However this seems to be for UNIX, and I'm on Windows. So my question is, is there a similar technique such that I can run my c++ program and use it's data in Python??

Comment: It's almost exactly the same on Windows.

Comment: related/dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466801/python-piping-on-windows-why-does-this-not-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However this seems to be for UNIX, and I'm on Windows. So my question is, is there a similar technique such that I can run my c++ program and use it's data in Python??

As mentioned [here](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true) the windows `cmd.exe` shell (and powershell also) support the `|` symbol the same way, as linux/unix shells do.

A bit of a special thing (for both kind of OS) is you need to invoke the python interpreter explicitly. So running your stuff like

```
mycppprogram | python mypyscript.py
```

should work to achieve what you want.

Comment: @user3080432 You may consider to accept my answer, if it worked out well for you.